# spring xd file as source not working in stream case

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to use `spring xd` to read from file as a source and put the data in a `jdbc`, I tried the job batch filejdbc using the following:

```
xd:>job create csvtojdbc --definition "filejdbc --resources=file:\Batch\sourcecsv.csv --names=id,name,gender --tableName=csvfiletomysql_tbl2 --username=bigdata --password=bigdata --delimiter=, --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --initializeDatabase=true" --deploy
```

It worked properly, but the issue is that it is not working (file as a source) in case of streams, I tried this also, but this also did not work

```
xd:>stream create sourcecsv --definition "file --outputType=text/plain | json-to-tuple |jdbc --columns=id,name,gender --tableName=csvfiletomysql_tbl3 --username=bigdata --password=bigdata --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --initializeDatabase=true" --deploy
```

Comment: You can ignore this part --outputType=text/plain | json-to-tuple it is not working either way!!

Answer (score 0):

"It's not working" is simply not enough information for anyone to help you. Turn on DEBUG logging on the container; if you still can't figure it out post the log someplace.

You also need to provide version information.

By default the file source emits the whole file as a single message; if you have multiple lines you need to split it.

The [1.2 file source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#file) has `mode=lines` to emit each line as a single message.

Comment: Thanks Gray for the reply,
I am using 1.2.0 Spring XD Release.

Comment: Thanks Gray for the reply,
I am using 1.2.0 Spring XD Release.
I am using xd single node, MySQL is installed on my PC.
I located the MySQL driver under xd/lib
I edited the servers.yml file, and amended the MySQL configuration as the followings:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: bigdata
    password: bigdata
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    validationQuery: select 1

Comment: I think no problem with MySQL Driver and configuration because it is working when I user job batch.
The file is a csv file "comma delimiter"
1 Moha Male
2 Manal Female
3 Sami Male
when I executed the below stream 
xd:>stream create sourcecsv --definition "file --mode=lines |jdbc --columns=id,name,gender --tableNa
me=csvfiletomysql_tbl --username=bigdata --password=bigdata --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test -
-driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --initializeDatabase=true" --deploy
The table structure is created but with no data.!!
The server did not show any error.

Comment: No Server Error. The log is too long to attach.

Comment: The csv file is located under the default path /tmp/xd/input

Comment: As I said, you need to turn on DEBUG logging for the singlenode and post the log someplace, if you can't figure it out yourself. If the log is too big to post here, you need to find somewhere else (e.g. pastebin or a github gist).